# RSpec Load specific seed data for specific tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, model

In Ruby on Rails 4/RSpec/Capybara model testing I need some seed data loaded for one specific test file that wouldn't be used in any other tests.  Is there a proper protocol for writing a separate 'seed' file for a situation like this.

I've researched SO and found a reference to `load #{Rails.root/db/(filename.rb)` but it seemed like many disputed this was the proper way to do it.

Comment: Can you add one of the tests

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII I could add the test file I guess but not sure how it would help - I need to know how to load seed data only under a specific context - and make sure it's erased afterwards

Comment: You can implement seeds as a [Shared context is RSpec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context) and then use it only in specific test with `include_context "my seeds"`. But I think approach with load file is also appropriate only the file should be located somewhere in `spec/fixtures`

Comment: @OleksandrAvoyants If you put that as the answer I can mark it as the correct one as it seems to be my solution on a quick scan

Comment: MageeWorld It would help because I was considering using a shared context block but I wanted to know more about how your test were already structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement seeds as a [Shared context is RSpec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context) and then use it only in specific test with `include_context "my seeds"`. But I think approach with load file is also appropriate only the file should be located somewhere in `spec/fixtures`